# text of textbox bind with jquery datepicker getting null value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have textbox named 'txtExploitDate' in update panel. And on button click I have set default value for textbox as yesterday's date. I have written below jquery code to bind datepicker with textbox. But when I select date from datepicker it is refleting date in textbox just for second and again changing to default date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function DatePickerExploitDate() {
    //    $(function () {
    //        $("#txtExploitDate").datepicker();
    //    });
    //});
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ApplyDatePicker();
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ApplyDatePicker);
    });

    function ApplyDatePicker() {
        $('#txtExploitDate').datepicker();
    }
</script>
```

Please ignore the commented code as I was using it earlier when my textbox was not in update panel but there was postback issue that time so I put my textbox in update panel and changed my jquery code.

Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

That is because JQuery datepicker uses unique IDs for all controls that use the plugin. This is something done by most JQuery plugins to control events. When the update panel refreshes those special unique IDs don't point anywhere anymore.

Check the explanation and solution in this article from asp snippets: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-DatePicker-not-working-inside-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack.aspx

Resolution is made possible by having the plugin rerun when update panel refreshes.

As a personal point of view I believe you should try to see a solution without update panel as it is a very cumbersome technology, is to break when you start to mess with the DOM and there is better ways to use AJAX calls, even with JQuery.